# Custom Receiver fails to launch correctly

Tags: java, android, chromecast

When I am connecting to the CC device form my Sender application, often the Custom Receiver does not launch properly.

It will load, but will never be in a ready state.

Here is the logcat output:

```
01-21 14:16:09.603  19396-19396/com.example.chromecast D/PlayActivity onRouteSelected
01-21 14:16:16.913  19396-19396/com.example.chromecast D/PlayActivity onConnected
01-21 14:16:16.953  19396-19396/com.example.chromecast D/ccl_BaseCastManager﹕ [v1.11] onConnected() reached with prior suspension: false
01-21 14:16:16.953  19396-19396/com.example.chromecast D/ccl_BaseCastManager﹕ [v1.11] launchApp() is called
01-21 14:16:16.953  19396-19396/com.example.chromecast D/ccl_BaseCastManager﹕ [v1.11] Launching app
01-21 14:16:17.003  19396-19396/com.example.chromecast D/ccl_DataCastManager﹕ [v1.11] onApplicationStatusChanged() reached:
01-21 14:16:19.513  19396-19396/com.example.chromecast D/ccl_DataCastManager﹕ [v1.11] onApplicationStatusChanged() reached: null
01-21 14:16:20.633  19396-19396/com.example.chromecast D/ccl_BaseCastManager﹕ [v1.11] launchApplication() -> failure result
01-21 14:16:20.633  19396-19396/com.example.chromecast D/ccl_BaseCastManager﹕ [v1.11] disconnectDevice(true,false)
01-21 14:16:20.633  19396-19396/com.example.chromecast D/ccl_BaseCastManager﹕ [v1.11] mConnectionSuspended: false
01-21 14:16:20.633  19396-19396/com.example.chromecast D/ccl_BaseCastManager﹕ [v1.11] clearPersistedConnectionInfo(): Clearing persisted data for 0
01-21 14:16:20.653  19396-19396/com.example.chromecast D/ccl_BaseCastManager﹕ [v1.11] onDisconnected() reached
01-21 14:16:20.653  19396-19396/com.example.chromecast D/ccl_BaseCastManager﹕ [v1.11] Trying to disconnect
01-21 14:16:37.295  19396-19396/com.example.chromecast D/PlayActivity ApplicationConnectionResultCallback.onResult: statusCode15
01-21 14:16:37.295  19396-19396/com.example.chromecast E/PlayActivity application could not launch
01-21 14:16:37.295  19396-19396/com.example.chromecast D/PlayActivity teardown
```

If I disconnect in my Sender app, then re-connect, the Receiver will get into the ready state and I can cast my content.

What would be causing this behaviour? (It happens more often then not and is very fustrating!)

Some code:

(Media Route initialisation)

```
mMediaRouter = MediaRouter.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    mMediaRouteSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
            .addControlCategory(
                    CastMediaControlIntent.categoryForCast(getResources()
                            .getString(R.string.app_id))).build();
    mMediaRouterCallback = new MyMediaRouterCallback();

    mDataCastManager = DataCastManager.initialize(this, getResources().getString(R.string.app_id), getResources().getString(R.string.namespace));
    mDataCastManager.reconnectSessionIfPossible(this, true, 20);
```

Media Route button

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem mediaRouteMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.media_route_menu_item);
    MediaRouteActionProvider mediaRouteActionProvider = (MediaRouteActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(mediaRouteMenuItem);
    mediaRouteActionProvider.setRouteSelector(mMediaRouteSelector);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Callbacks

```
private class MyMediaRouterCallback extends MediaRouter.Callback {

    @Override
    public void onRouteSelected(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo info) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRouteSelected");
        // Handle the user route selection.
        mSelectedDevice = CastDevice.getFromBundle(info.getExtras());

        launchReceiver();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRouteUnselected(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo info) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRouteUnselected: info=" + info);
        teardown();
        mSelectedDevice = null;
    }
}
```

As you can see, most of my implementation is from the CastHelloText Android sample application. I have added in the CCL library to allow easy session management, but I think that is causing the issue.

Commenting out the DataCastManager seems to give much better results when connecting the the CC device for casting.

Comment: How about some code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CCL, then stop managing the media router button, the direct callbacks from media router, launching receiver, etc since those are handled by CCL. If you want to do those things yourself, then stop using CCL; you are currently mixing two different things in a wrong way. Reading the docs on CCL can be helpful.

Comment: Well it'd be great if the documentation didn't solely concentrate on the video casting aspect. I was unaware that I should either use CCL, or not. I wrongly assumed I could just use parts of it. Could you possibly provide some example code on how I should use CCL in place of the default Cast SDK implementation?

Comment: Had you read the documentation, you would have noticed that it does talk about the DataCastManager as well (so it is not solely about video casting). I don't have a sample for using DataCastManager.

Comment: I'm specifically looking for a DataCastManager sample.

Comment: As I said, we don't have one but can't see why you would have issues if you follow the docs; you initialize it, you set up your media route action provider in onCreateOptionsMenu() (identical to what you would do for VideoCastManager) and add incrementUi/decrementUi to your onResume()/onPause() and that should be enough to get the connection related stuff up and running.